# Can a wave be modulated in such a way such that it can calculate the time the wave existed from the transmitter to the receiver

Tags: waves

Can a wave be modulated in such a way or by any other techniques or program it? I know it sounds impossible but can there be a way to do the above task?

Comment: if you know the propagation velocity *and* the distance between T and R then the arrival time of a pulse or a "compressed pulse" will also indicate the instant of emission.

Comment: I have to calculate the distance

Comment: in that case you have to *synchronize* the emitter and the receiver clocks, and then measure the time of arrival.